# How do I build a Visual Studio project from inside a C++ program, using system() to access command line?

Tags: c++, cmd

I'm trying to make a Visual Studio project build/compilation from the command line, but from inside a C++ program. I can get this working if I use the command line directly and running the following:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\My Project Folder
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\\IDE\devenv.exe" MyProject.sln /Build Release
```

The trouble is that these commands are not working from inside a C++ program using `system()` like so:

```
system("cd C:\\Program Files (x86)\\My Project Folder");
system("\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe\" MyProject.sln /Build Release");
```

Can anyone help me to get these commands working from inside the C++program?

Comment: Did you read the Microsoft documentations of the [system function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/system-function) and of [system, _wsystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem)? There is executed on Windows in background `%ComSpec% /c` with the command line as defined in C++ source code file appended as additional arguments which means there is usually executed `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` (64-bit version on 64-bit Windows, 32-bit version on 32-bit Windows) or `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` (32-bit version on 64-bit Windows).

Comment: Which `cmd.exe` is executed on 64-bit Windows depends on compiled executable being a 32-bit or 64-bit program and the Windows [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector). There is used by `system` the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) to start `cmd.exe`. The Windows Command Processor uses also `CreateProcess` to run `devenv.exe`.

Comment: Why is not used the ANSI or Unicode version of the kernel function `CreateProcess` directly with appropriate string values for `lpApplicationName`, `lpCommandLine`, `lpCurrentDirectory` without or with a properly filled out [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure? That would be better as it would be possible with using `CreateProcess` to evaluate the exit code of `devenv.exe` and capture standard and error output. The roundabout route via `cmd.exe` called with `system` function is not needed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a couple of changes:

1. Each `system()` call is new, so you will need to use `&&` to do multiple commands
2. You need to escape quotation marks with `\"` otherwise the quotations will be used to denote a string instead of being passed to cmd
3. You need to use 2 backslashes in the path `\\`

Eg.

```cpp
system("cd \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\My Project Folder\" && \"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe\" MyProject.sln /Build Release");
```

I suggest using raw string literals for better readability.

```cpp
system(R"(cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\My Project Folder" && "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" MyProject.sln /Build Release)");
```